# Activate ox-extras on a per document basis

Tags: org-mode, org-export

The org mode export utilities in `ox-extra` are very useful. However because these utilities are enabled in my `init.el` file, I do not know how to enable or disable the utilities and a per document basis.

Specifically, my init.el contains:

```
(require 'ox-extra)
(ox-extras-activate '(notignore-headlines))
```

This activates `notignore-headlines` globally. Can this instead be activated  on a per document basis?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that support is on the `org-extra` to-do list (from `org-extra.el`):

```
;; TODO:
;; - add a function to org-mode-hook that looks for a ox-extras local
;;   variable and activates the specified extras buffer-locally
```

In the meantime you can circumvent `ox-extras-activate` by adding something like this to the top of the file you want it active for:

```
# -*- eval: (progn (require 'ox-extra) (add-hook 'org-export-filter-parse-tree-functions 'org-export-notignore-headlines nil t)); -*-
```

(judging from this commit: https://github.com/boykov/org-mode/compare/ox-extra-notignore)

Note that you need to pass the `LOCAL` `t` argument to `add-hook`.

Comment: @ ebpa Can you help me with the syntax for the suggested workaround? Placing the add-hook code at the start of the buffer seems to have no effect on the exported pdf.

Comment: @Snelephant If you save that at the top of the file and re-open / revert the buffer it should take effect.  Emacs will likely ask you if you want to apply eval entry the first time you open it.  If it's still not working I might have a typo.  Could you check whether it works manually / whether the `org-export-*` symbols are accurate?

Comment: @ ebpa Saving and reloading the relevant buffer triggered the eval. However, upon confirming I receive: `byte-code: Symbol’s function definition is void: t`

Comment: @Snelephant Hmm.  Maybe add-hook has a different signature on your system?  I think there was a `add-local-hook` function for a while.  The arguments I provided were for the `add-hook` signature `(add-hook HOOK FUNCTION &optional APPEND LOCAL)`.  What version of emacs are you running?

Comment: @ ebpa Emacs 25.1. Several add-hook entries in my init.el seem work. To clarify, the error above occurs during export.

Comment: @Snelephant try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to pause on the error and see the stack trace

Comment: @ ebpa Pausing on the error produces a lengthy stack trace. What in particular I should look for?